# Azure oauth2 authentication with proxy server

Tags: spring-boot, azure, oauth-2.0, proxy

I developed a Spring Boot web application using Azure oauth2 authentication and its working fine without proxy server. However now there is a requirement to add a proxy server between client request and application server.
I'm facing issue when application server redirect the unauthorized request to Microsoft authentication page proxy server not redirecting to the Microsoft authentication page.

When new request hit the application server its suppose to redirect URL similar to below

https://login.microsoftonline.com/616ddddd-077e-1113c-ae11-70bad51111b/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=eaaaaa119-112a-435e-93dd-9c805a2158d7&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read&state=oIqkKJ_ye3Di3faaaaaarM7WAaaaa_PPbj4nVo8Yzs%3D&redirect_uri=https://mydomain/login/oauth2/code/azure-dev&nonce=umgLar3jtoobaaaaaaaaaJFEW0QpeNYK-CbG_M

how ever with proxy server response which get to browser is something similar to below. The highlited parts all correct parameter only issue facing on this request is its not on Microsoft domain.

https://mydomain/**616ddddd-077e-1113c-ae11-70bad51111b/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=eaaaaa119-112a-435e-93dd-9c805a2158d7&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read&state=oIqkKJ_ye3Di3faaaaaarM7WAaaaa_PPbj4nVo8Yzs%3D&redirect_uri=https://mydomain/login/oauth2/code/azure-dev&nonce=umgLar3jtoobaaaaaaaaaJFEW0QpeNYK-CbG_M**

Would like to check anyone experience this kind of error when deploying Azure authenticated app with proxy server.